# ArangoDB AQL FILTER graph for matching edge attributes

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I have one `words` collection and one `word_relations` edge collection. Words have relationships to other words, like *synonym*, *hasPart*, *partOf*, *hasType*, *typeOf*, etc.

I am trying to figure out how to `FILTER` an AQL graph query so that all paths are followed, but paths with more than one edge contain identical edge attribute of `relation_type`.

E.g., I want this result (all returned paths, whether one or many, contain a single `relation_type` attribute value):

```
[
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/organism",
        "relation_type": "typeOf"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "organism",
        "word": "organism"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/organism",
        "relation_type": "typeOf"
      },
      {
        "_from": "library/organism",
        "_to": "library/scheme",
        "relation_type": "typeOf"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "organism",
        "word": "organism"
      },
      {
        "_key": "scheme",
        "word": "scheme"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/stepparent",
        "relation_type": "hasType"
      },
      {
        "_from": "library/stepparent",
        "_to": "library/stepmother",
        "relation_type": "hasType"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "stepparent",
        "word": "stepparent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "stepmother",
        "word": "stepmother"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

NOT this result (the `relation_type` attribute value changes within one path):

```
[
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/organism",
        "relation_type": "typeOf"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "organism",
        "word": "organism"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/organism",
        "relation_type": "typeOf"
      },
      {
        "_from": "library/organism",
        "_to": "library/zygote",
        "relation_type": "hasCategories"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "organism",
        "word": "organism"
      },
      {
        "_key": "zygote",
        "word": "zygote"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_from": "library/parent",
        "_to": "library/family_unit",
        "relation_type": "memberOf"
      },
      {
        "_from": "library/family_unit",
        "_to": "library/sibling",
        "relation_type": "hasMembers"
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "parent",
        "word": "parent"
      },
      {
        "_key": "family_unit",
        "word": "family unit"
      },
      {
        "_key": "sibling",
        "word": "sibling"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

There are many different kinds of `relation_type` attribute values. I do not want to filter to a specific value, I don't care what the initial value is, I just want all follow-on attribute values to be the same as the first.

The AQL to get the second (undesirable) result looks like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND 'words/parent' word_relations
  RETURN p
```

I have tried a few different filters, none of which work:

0 results:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND 'library/parent' library_relations
  FILTER p.edges[*].relation_type ALL == p.edges[*].relation_type
  RETURN p
```

Only returns 2 paths, b/c the `FILTER` requires the second to exist:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND 'library/parent' library_relations
  FILTER p.edges[0].relation_type == p.edges[1].relation_type
  RETURN p
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following could be used for larger values of MAX as well:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND 'library/parent' library_relations
  FILTER p.edges[*].relation_type ALL == e.relation_type
  RETURN p
```

Unfortunately, the AQL optimizer is tragically impaired at the moment (see https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/3979#issuecomment-350686061), so most likely you would have to work around its limitation, e.g. by prepending the above with:

```
FOR tmpV, tmpE  IN 1..1 OUTBOUND 'library/parent’ library_relations
```

and then using `tmpE.relation_type` instead of `e.relation_type`.